# How to convert stringbuilder text and get pdf format file output in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and I need to convert some stringbulider text and get pdf format output file on button click event..

Following is sample stringbuilder text.

```
StringBuilder reqReport = new StringBuilder();
reqReport.Append("<li>Five copies of your latest Passport size.</li>");
reqReport.Append("<li>Your certificates, testimonials etc. (in original with one photocopy)</li>");
reqReport.Append("<li>Residence & Identity proof required in Bank account opening process as per RBI guidelines.</li>");
```

I tried using itextsharp..

```
string html = reqReport.ToString();
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
pdfDoc.Open();
System.Xml.XmlTextReader _xmlr = new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(new StringReader(html));
HtmlParser.Parse(pdfDoc, _xmlr);
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Table.pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
Response.End();
```

This creates the pdf file.. But when I try to open the file, it shows the the file is either corrupted or damaged and could not be opened..

Is there any other format to do the function..?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hi, even I am getting same error.. do you remember what changes have you done for this fix?